# Fantastic Definition of Skepticism

Tags: discussion

I was cruising over at JREF (stalking Larian as usual), and saw [a post](http://forums.randi.org/showpost.php?p=8698451&postcount=54) that I think is a great way to explain to people what Skepticism is:

> Skepticism is the willingness to subject anything and everything to the harshest possible scrutiny. If you have never changed your mind on any subject, ever, you probably aren't a skeptic.
>
> In other words, skepticism isn't so much about being right, but avoiding being wrong. Debunking is the process of showing why something is wrong, and therefor why it should be avoided.

Just wanted to share (Larian thought it was a good post).

Comment: And I see a related question on this: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/259/has-skepticism-been-defined?rq=1  I suppose I am a day late on this...

Comment: Thanks for posting this here.  I already had a chance to use it.